# Angularjs: Does all code (html, js) loads initially or it happens based on request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Confused about when Angularjs application is bootstrapped, then all of the code js files(controllers, services, etc) and html(templates for controllers) are loaded initially before rendering any page or it is loaded based on request like lazy loading.

According to me all javascript code gets loaded and templates are rendered based on request. Please correct me. And also clear if answer for this changes if routing is implemented or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Angular 1 app, all JavaScript is loaded immediately. Code in functions which is not called immediately is run later on. But still all code is parsed immediately.

Controller code is executed asynchronously when its DOM is activated on the page. For instance via `ng-if` (not `ng-show`). Same applies to `link` callbacks. Here is a detailled description of the execution order: 
[Practical Guide to PreLink, PostLink and Controller Methods of Angular Directives](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives)

The DOM is changed asynchronously and dynamically.

Comment: What about html files for different routes, does that load based on request or that too gets load initially?

Comment: Different routes stay on the same page and are only loaded by JavaScript. It is all asynchronous. All JavaScript is always loaded initially, but not executed initially.

Comment: Ok, got your point, so whatever javascript code which initializes the app gets executed, and other controllers if exists just gets loaded but not executed and the templates for the controllers are retrieved only when requested(switched to).

Comment: I have one doubt in this, if templates are loaded asynchronously then request has to go server side and template has to be retrieved then how come page loads instantaneously?

Comment: The content of the route loads delayed (not instantaneously). Open your browser's developer tools on the following example and switch to the network tab. Then click "About" or "Contact". You can see a delay of several milliseconds (> 300 ms on my computer with my Internet connection): http://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg. Each template is only loaded once then cached and re-used.

Comment: Understood. Thanks @ideaboxer.